# how to mix two color with different percent

Tags: android, colors

i have two color and a View component. color one is background of my component. i will change my background Color to color two. but not suddenly. change similar a animation. for example:

second 1 : 90% color1  + 10% color2
second 1 : 80% color1  + 20% color2
......
second 1 : 10% color1  + 90% color2
second 1 : 0% color1   + 100% color2

of course i try it :

```
percent=100;
while (percent>=0) {
    color = (color1*precent)+(color2*(100-percent));  
    percent-=10;
}
```

but this is a bad idea.the result is disappointing.
is there any solution for this target.
thanks.

Comment: you'll have to separate r, g, and b for that

Comment: Unclear if it's the same color with different alpha or just other color, possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614545/animate-change-of-view-background-color-in-android

Comment: but i use custom view. i will set this animation in a small portion of this view. not in all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't clearly say why the result is disappointing, so I'm assuming it means the color transition you get is not as good you expected it to be.

Your general approach seems right, maybe you are just missing some detail so I will rewrite it in different terms. Let `color1` and `color2` be triples (R, G, B) where each of R, G, B is in range [0, 1]. If that is not the case, divide by 255 if that is the limit in your situation, and later multiply again by 255. Let `s` be the number of steps to transition from `color1` to `color2`, here I'm including in `s` the initial frame with `color1` but not the final frame with `color2`. At step `k`, you have a value `p` such that `p = (s - k)/s`. With `p` you obtain the color in frame `k` by doing `color = p * color1 + (1 - p) * color2`. Now you may want to multiply `color` by 255.

A pseudocode for this description is:

```
color1 = (R1, G1, B1)
color2 = (R2, G2, B2)
s = N

for k = 0 to s: # s + 1 steps, according to the description
    p = (s - k) / s
    color = (p * color1) + ((1 - p) * color2)
```

Note that at `k = 0` you have only `color1`, and at `k = s` you get only `color2`. As you see, it is similar to what you posted with more details. Note that here I'm multiplying each of R, G, B by `p`.

Here are some examples transitioning from a yellow to some blue color, `steps = 10, 25, 500` respectively.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: While everything you say is logically true, it's possible to implement something that accomplishes this which is many times more efficient computation-wise that what is outlined in the pseudo-code -- which may be important especially for doing animation.

Comment: @martineau Would you care to elaborate on this more efficient computation-wise method of colour changing?

Comment: @Glenn: See my answers to [Python - Range values to pseudocolor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901085/python-range-values-to-pseudocolor) and [Mandelbrot-algorithm - Background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253547/mandelbrot-algorithm-background-color). There's also some good information on the subject in the Wikipedia article [Linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerp_%28computing%29) (aka Lerp). It's also possible to do it additively, without any multiplication or division in the inner loop.