# Generating color gradient in Python

Tags: python, colors, python-imaging-library, draw, gradient

i have a list of RGB colors and need to draw gradient between them in python. Have you any suggestions how to make it usin PIL library?

EDIT:
I get this:

```
def gradient(list_of_colors):
    width = 600
    height = 480
    img = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    for i in range(len(list_of_colors)):
        r1,g1,b1 = list_of_colors[i]
        for x in range(width/len(list_of_colors)):
            colour = (r1,g1,b1)
            draw.line((x+(width/len(list_of_colors)*i), 0, x+(width/len(list_of_colors)*i), height), fill=colour)

    img.show()

gradient([(30, 198, 244), (99, 200, 72),(120, 50, 80),(200, 90, 140)])
```

and it draw me this:
http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/1852/3gba.png

I just need to make it gradient between those colors not stripes of colors.
(something like this) http://www.kees-tm.nl/uploads/colorgradient.jpg

Comment: See my answer to [_Python - Range values to pseudocolor_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901085/python-range-values-to-pseudocolor/10907855#10907855).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is nearly there! For the community to better answer, please edit it to include *how the output of your code does not meet your expectations*, and what you have tried in the contex of `PIL`. For more information, please re-read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22607043/5987

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create colour gradient in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668828/how-to-create-colour-gradient-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

I think code like this will work, it uses [Linear Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) to create the gradient.

```
list_of_colors = [(30, 198, 244), (99, 200, 72),(120, 50, 80),(200, 90, 140)]

no_steps = 100

def LerpColour(c1,c2,t):
    return (c1[0]+(c2[0]-c1[0])*t,c1[1]+(c2[1]-c1[1])*t,c1[2]+(c2[2]-c1[2])*t)

for i in range(len(list_of_colors)-2):
    for j in range(no_steps):
        colour = LerpColour(list_of_colors[i],list_of_colors[i+1],j/no_steps)
```

Obviously I don't know how you are drawing the gradient so I've left it open to you, do what you like with the colour variable to draw each step of the gradient within the for loop. :)

Also: I don't understand list generation so if anyone can improve the LerpColour function to use it please edit my post :)

EDIT -
Generating a list that can easily be iterated over when drawing with PIL:

```
gradient = []
for i in range(len(list_of_colors)-2):
    for j in range(no_steps):
        gradient.append(LerpColour(list_of_colors[i],list_of_colors[i+1],j/no_steps))
```

Comment: applied you idea but still no changes, i still get lines of color not gradient

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of what you have, and a mock up of what you want? That way I (and others) will have a better idea of what we're aiming at :)

Comment: I get this [link](http://imageshack.us/a/img59/1852/3gba.png) and want something like this [link](http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/7903/89q3.png) for any colors i put into that list

Answer (score 0):

I've built my own thing for my own needs after trying to find something that could compute gradients efficiently on multi-dimensional arrays
so I hope you don't mind alpha processing :)

```py
def colorscale( r:int,g:int,b:int,a:int, R:int,G:int,B:int,A:int, s:float ) -> tuple:
    S = 1.-s
    return round(r*S+R*s),round(g*S+G*s),round(b*S+B*s),round(a*S+A*s)
```

this takes the same approach as [JamJar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20586224/2131849) `LerpColour`, but I did the scaling in a more simplistic way.

though it's probably not the most efficient due to `round()`, but I needed the accuracy...

that said, alternatively you can use scalar (0.0 - 1.0) colors (like I am), to get rid of `round()` entirely ;)

```py
def colorscale( r:float,g:float,b:float,a:float, R:float,G:float,B:float,A:float, s:float ) -> tuple:
    S = 1.-s
    return r*S+R*s,g*S+G*s,b*S+B*s,a*S+A*s
```

anyways, I know it's a late response, but I hope this answer helps anyone who needs it.

Comment: Linear interpolation is probably the most common way to create a gradient, but it's rarely the best.