# How to create colour gradient in Python?

Tags: python, colors, gradient

I want to create a new colormap which interpolates between green and blue (or any other two colours for that matter). My goal is to get something like: [image: gradient]

First of all I am really not sure if this can be done using linear interpolation of blue and green. If it can, I'm not sure how to do so, I found some documentation on using a matplotlib method that interpolates specified RGB values [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html)

The real trouble is understanding how "cdict2" works below. For the example the documentation says:

"Example: suppose you want red to increase from 0 to 1 over the bottom half, green to do the same over the middle half, and blue over the top half. Then you would use:"

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib 
import numpy as np

plt.figure()
a=np.outer(np.arange(0,1,0.01),np.ones(10))
cdict2 = {'red':   [(0.0,  0.0, 0.0),
                   (0.5,  1.0, 1.0),
                   (1.0,  1.0, 1.0)],
         'green': [(0.0,  0.0, 0.0),
                   (0.25, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (0.75, 1.0, 1.0),
                   (1.0,  1.0, 1.0)],
         'blue':  [(0.0,  0.0, 0.0),
                   (0.5,  0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0,  1.0, 1.0)]} 
my_cmap2 = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('my_colormap2',cdict2,256)
plt.imshow(a,aspect='auto', cmap =my_cmap2)                   
plt.show()
```

EDIT: I now understand how the interpolation works, for example this will give a red to white interpolation:

White to red: Going down the columns of the "matrix" for each colour, in column one we have the xcoordinate of where we want the interpolation to start and end and the two other columns are the actual values for the colour value at that coordinate.

```
cdict2 = {'red':   [(0.0,  1.0, 1.0),
                    (1.0,  1.0, 1.0),
                    (1.0,  1.0, 1.0)],
         'green': [(0.0,  1.0, 1.0),
                   (1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0,  0.0, 0.0)],
     'blue':  [(0.0,  1.0, 1.0),
               (1.0,  0.0, 0.0),
               (1.0,  0.0, 0.0)]}
```

It is evident that the gradient I want will be very difficult to create by interpolating in RGB space...

Comment: [Check out this link](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/named_colors.html) about the named colors. There's code in there that shows conversion between the specification methods. [I also think this link](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_only.html) about colorbars might help.

Comment: How did you create that example gradient? It's far from linear.

Comment: Yes absolutely, its just a screen shot illustrating what I want. I didn't create it. Im wondering if Python has some functions which facilitate those kinds of gradients...

Comment: A screen shot from *what* though?

Comment: I can try to find the slide I got it from, if that will help, but I just remember it being something that said "Here is an example of a colorgradient"

Answer (score 137):

A simple answer I have not seen yet is to just use the [colour package](https://pypi.org/project/colour/).

Install via pip

```
pip install colour
```

Use as so:

```py
from colour import Color
red = Color("red")
colors = list(red.range_to(Color("green"),10))
    
# colors is now a list of length 10
# Containing: 
# [<Color red>, <Color #f13600>, <Color #e36500>, <Color #d58e00>, <Color #c7b000>, <Color #a4b800>, <Color #72aa00>, <Color #459c00>, <Color #208e00>, <Color green>]
```

Change the inputs to any colors you want. As noted by @zelusp, this will *not* restrict itself to a smooth combination of only two colors (e.g. red to blue will have yellow+green in the middle), but based on the upvotes it's clear a number of folks find this to be a useful approximation

Comment: Gradients produced by this method pass through other colors to form a gradient - It's not a true gradient of only two colors - i.e. using this to go from red to blue will generate yellow and green colors.

Comment: [This page](https://bsou.io/posts/color-gradients-with-python) is a phenomenal resource about color gradation in Python

Comment: at least the package name is spelt correctly compared with the example .... ;p

Comment: This is a HSV gradient. The author could specify that in either the answer, or his code. Otherwise, good job.

Answer (score 59):

If you just need to **interpolate in between 2 colors**, I wrote a simple function for that. `colorFader` creates you a hex color code out of two other hex color codes.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def colorFader(c1,c2,mix=0): #fade (linear interpolate) from color c1 (at mix=0) to c2 (mix=1)
    c1=np.array(mpl.colors.to_rgb(c1))
    c2=np.array(mpl.colors.to_rgb(c2))
    return mpl.colors.to_hex((1-mix)*c1 + mix*c2)

c1='#1f77b4' #blue
c2='green' #green
n=500

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))
for x in range(n+1):
    ax.axvline(x, color=colorFader(c1,c2,x/n), linewidth=4) 
plt.show()
```

**result:**

[image: simple color mixing in python]

**update due to high interest:**

`colorFader` works now for rgb-colors and color-strings like 'red' or even 'r'.

Comment: this is failing for   c1='#ff0000' #red and  c2='#001dff' #blue

Comment: This a great answer. Works for me if I substitute `hex(a)[2:]` with `hex(a)[2:4]`.

Comment: @Ulf Alsak: Thanks for letting me know! Did you change anything in my code bevore executing? Maybe you can give an example about the content of `hex(a)`?

Comment: Yes! I actually miscommented above, I meant `hex(a)[2:-1]`. In my environment, `hex` returns a string that ends on "L", and you do not want to include that, hence the `-1`.

Comment: @Ulf Alsak: Completely updated. Should work on your system as well ;)

Comment: Thanks I used this in this small project: https://github.com/akosnikhazy/Budapest-Temperature

Comment: how would you make this a vertical gradient?

Comment: @Eddy `axhline`

Answer (score 42):

It's obvious that your original example gradient is *not* linear. Have a look at a graph of the red, green, and blue values averaged across the image:

[image: example gradient graph]

Attempting to recreate this with a combination of linear gradients is going to be difficult.

To me each color looks like the addition of two gaussian curves, so I did some best fits and came up with this:

[image: simulated]

Using these calculated values lets me create a really pretty gradient that matches yours almost exactly.

```
import math
from PIL import Image
im = Image.new('RGB', (604, 62))
ld = im.load()

def gaussian(x, a, b, c, d=0):
    return a * math.exp(-(x - b)**2 / (2 * c**2)) + d

for x in range(im.size[0]):
    r = int(gaussian(x, 158.8242, 201, 87.0739) + gaussian(x, 158.8242, 402, 87.0739))
    g = int(gaussian(x, 129.9851, 157.7571, 108.0298) + gaussian(x, 200.6831, 399.4535, 143.6828))
    b = int(gaussian(x, 231.3135, 206.4774, 201.5447) + gaussian(x, 17.1017, 395.8819, 39.3148))
    for y in range(im.size[1]):
        ld[x, y] = (r, g, b)
```

[image: recreated gradient]

Unfortunately I don't yet know how to generalize it to arbitrary colors.

Comment: Thanks Mark, this is great. I have also been experimenting with different curves, but as you say I struggle to find any way to generalise this for arbitrary colours. Perhaps looking at how some of the standard python gradients created here http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps would help, although I can't find code that shows how they were created.

Answer (score 11):

I needed this as well, but I wanted to enter multiple arbitrary color points. Consider a heat map where you need black, blue, green... all the way up to "hot" colors.  I borrowed [Mark Ransom](/users/5987/mark-ransom)'s code above and extended it to meet my needs.  I'm very happy with it.  My thanks to all, especially Mark.

This code is neutral to the size of the image (no constants in the gaussian distribution); you can change it with the width= parameter to pixel().  It also allows tuning the "spread" (-> stddev) of the distribution; you can muddle them up further or introduce black bands by changing the spread= parameter to pixel().

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

width, height = 1000, 200

import math
from PIL import Image
im = Image.new('RGB', (width, height))
ld = im.load()

# A map of rgb points in your distribution
# [distance, (r, g, b)]
# distance is percentage from left edge
heatmap = [
    [0.0, (0, 0, 0)],
    [0.20, (0, 0, .5)],
    [0.40, (0, .5, 0)],
    [0.60, (.5, 0, 0)],
    [0.80, (.75, .75, 0)],
    [0.90, (1.0, .75, 0)],
    [1.00, (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)],
]

def gaussian(x, a, b, c, d=0):
    return a * math.exp(-(x - b)**2 / (2 * c**2)) + d

def pixel(x, width=100, map=[], spread=1):
    width = float(width)
    r = sum([gaussian(x, p[1][0], p[0] * width, width/(spread*len(map))) for p in map])
    g = sum([gaussian(x, p[1][1], p[0] * width, width/(spread*len(map))) for p in map])
    b = sum([gaussian(x, p[1][2], p[0] * width, width/(spread*len(map))) for p in map])
    return min(1.0, r), min(1.0, g), min(1.0, b)

for x in range(im.size[0]):
    r, g, b = pixel(x, width=im.size[0], map=heatmap)
    r, g, b = [int(256*v) for v in (r, g, b)]
    for y in range(im.size[1]):
        ld[x, y] = r, g, b

im.save('grad.png')
```

Here's the multi-point gradient produced by this code:
[image: multi-point gradient produced by this code]

Answer (score 10):

[image]

This is a very compact way to create a colormap.
See also the documentation of [LinearSegmentedColormap](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list).

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

cmap0 = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
        'green2red', ['green', 'orangered'])
cmap1 = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
        'unevently divided', [(0, 'b'), (.3, 'gray'), (1, 'green')])

# plot
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1)
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1)
cbar = axs[0].figure.colorbar(
            mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap0),
            ax=axs[0], fraction=.1)
cbar = axs[1].figure.colorbar(
            mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap1),
            ax=axs[1], fraction=.1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is one of the most simple ways. Underappreciated. `mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('b2g', ['royalblue', 'w', 'forestgreen'])`

Answer (score 8):

This creates a colormap controlled by a single parameter, `y`:

```
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap


def bluegreen(y):
    red = [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.5, y, y), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)]
    green = [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.5, y, y), (1.0, y, y)]
    blue = [(0.0, y, y), (0.5, y, y),(1.0,0.0,0.0)]
    colordict = dict(red=red, green=green, blue=blue)
    bluegreenmap = LinearSegmentedColormap('bluegreen', colordict, 256)
    return bluegreenmap
```

`red` ramps up from 0 to `y` and then back down to 0.  `green` ramps up from 0 to `y` and then is constant.  `blue` stars at `y` and is constant for the first half, then ramps down to 0.

Here's the plot with `y = 0.7`:

[image: bluegreen color map]

You could smooth it out by using adding another segment or two.

Comment: Thanks for this great example. As you point out, some smoothing would be required. Right now we just have two piecewise linear functions that are 'mirrored' about the halfway point. I guess the ideal scenario would be to have two non-linear functions also mirrored about the halfway point and intersecting close to zero?

Comment: Yes, something like that.  @jcoppens has a more refined example.

Answer (score 8):

The first element of each tuple (0, 0.25, 0.5, etc) is the place where the color should be a certain value. I took 5 samples to see the RGB components (in GIMP), and placed them in the tables. The RGB components go from 0 to 1, so I had to divide them by 255.0 to scale the normal 0-255 values.

The 5 points are a rather coarse approximation - if you want a 'smoother' appearance, use more values.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib 
import numpy as np

plt.figure()
a=np.outer(np.arange(0,1,0.01),np.ones(10))
fact = 1.0/255.0
cdict2 = {'red':  [(0.0,   22*fact,  22*fact),
                   (0.25, 133*fact, 133*fact),
                   (0.5,  191*fact, 191*fact),
                   (0.75, 151*fact, 151*fact),
                   (1.0,   25*fact,  25*fact)],
         'green': [(0.0,   65*fact,  65*fact),
                   (0.25, 182*fact, 182*fact),
                   (0.5,  217*fact, 217*fact),
                   (0.75, 203*fact, 203*fact),
                   (1.0,   88*fact,  88*fact)],
         'blue':  [(0.0,  153*fact, 153*fact),
                   (0.25, 222*fact, 222*fact),
                   (0.5,  214*fact, 214*fact),
                   (0.75, 143*fact, 143*fact),
                   (1.0,   40*fact,  40*fact)]} 
my_cmap2 = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('my_colormap2',cdict2,256)
plt.imshow(a,aspect='auto', cmap =my_cmap2)                   
plt.show()
```

Note that red is quite present. It's there because the center area approaches gray - where the three components are necessary.

This produces: [image: result from the above table]

Comment: +1 for thinking outside the box, I never thought of actually sampling the components. Just out of curiosity, why does there need to be a 3rd column in the dictionary for each component, if the first value in each tuple is the position and the second is the value- what does the 3rd represent?

Comment: @Jack: The two values allow for a discontinuity in the color map.  If a point is `(x0, yleft, yright)`, the colormap approaches `yleft` as `x` increases to `x0`, and it approaches `yright` as `x` decreases to `x0`.

Comment: Great, thanks a bunch! I have to admit, this was more complicated than I had previously imagined. Using your method I can get what I want provided I have a gradient at my disposal to get the component values of. But what if I want to create some the above but for red and green etc. I guess that won't be so straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this [link](https://gist.github.com/redjack001/169e388d031925743b83f525552565e8) could help you solve your problem, thanks this code's author **redjack001**

```
from PIL import Image

#set the size of the new image
w = 500
h = 200

#start creating gradient
pixel_list = []
pixel_w = []

#colour at 0,0
start1 = (255,255,255)
s = list(start1)
pixel_list.append(start1)
print('Position zero:', pixel_list[0])

#colour at end
end1 = (174,15,15)
e = list(end1)

#in case you want to change the final colour you could use f to adjust otherwise just keep it at 1
f = 1

#transition per line
r = (s[0] - e[0])/w*f
g = (s[1] - e[1])/w*f
b = (s[2] - e[2])/w*f

t = ()

for j in range (0,w):
    t = pixel_list[j]

    #convert pixel tuple to a list and recalculate
    li = list(t)
    li[0] = int(max((li[0] - r*j),0))
    li[1] = int(max((li[1] - g*j),0))
    li[2] = int(max((li[2] - b*j),0))
    z = (li[0],li[1],li[2])
    final_t = tuple(z)
    #print('final_t:', final_t) if you want to show the list of pixel values
    pixel_list[j] = final_t
    for i in range (0,h):
        pixel_w = []
        pixel_w.append(final_t)
        pixel_list.extend(pixel_w)

l = len(pixel_list)

print('Pixel_list:', pixel_list, l)


#remove the last item
del pixel_list[l-1:]

print('Reprint length:', len(pixel_list))

im = Image.new('RGB', (w,h))
im.putdata(pixel_list)
im.show()
```

the result is here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For what is worth, here is a neat numpy way of interpolating between two colors:

```
def h_kernel(shape):
    row = np.linspace(0, 1, shape[1])
    kernel_1d = np.tile(row, (shape[0], 1))
    kernel_3d = cv2.merge((kernel_1d, kernel_1d, kernel_1d))
    return kernel_3d


def v_kernel(shape):
    kernel = h_kernel((shape[1], shape[0], shape[2]))
    return cv2.rotate(kernel, cv2.cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)


def gradient(shape, c1, c2, kernel_func):
    im = np.zeros(shape)
    kernel = h_kernel(shape)
    im = kernel * c1 + (1 - kernel) * c2
    return im.astype(np.uint8)

shape = (540, 960)
c1 = np.array((182, 132, 69))  # bgr
c2 = np.array((47, 32, 9))
h_gradient = gradient(shape, c1, c2, h_kernel)
v_gradient = gradient(shape, c1, c2, v_kernel)
cv2.imwrite("h.png", h_gradient)
cv2.imwrite("v.png", v_gradient)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: why vertical one is not working !!??

Comment: Oops, the arguments to the imshow function were incomplete. I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

A variation of J.Zhao's post which hopefully simplifies what is happening

```
def generateGradientBackground(w_ori, h_ori, r, g, b, brightness=1, reverse=False):

    # generate a vertical gradient between a colour and white
    # create the 1st column 1 pixel wide with all the colour ranges needed
    # then copy this horizontally for as many pixels width needed

    if reverse:
        s = (255*brightness,255*brightness,255*brightness)
        e = (r*brightness,g*brightness,b*brightness)
    else:
        s = (r*brightness,g*brightness,b*brightness)
        e = (255*brightness,255*brightness,255*brightness)

    #transition per line
    r = (s[0] - e[0])/(h_ori-1)
    g = (s[1] - e[1])/(h_ori-1)
    b = (s[2] - e[2])/(h_ori-1)

    t = ()

    for h in range (h_ori):
        # get new pixel colour
        p = (
            int(max((s[0] - r*h),0)),
            int(max((s[1] - g*h),0)),
            int(max((s[2] - b*h),0))
        )

        hlist.append(p)
        
    # now we have all the pixels for 1 column

    for p in hlist:
        tp = ( (p,) * w_ori )
        pixel_list += list( tp )

    im = Image.new('RGB', (w_ori,h_ori))
    im.putdata(pixel_list)
    #im.show()
    #im.save("background.png")
    return im
```