# How to get rainbow RGV values relative to a list length (i.e. 100)

Tags: python, colors, data-visualization

I've tried the answer posted here: [Calculate RGB value for a range of values to create heat map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792445/calculate-rgb-value-for-a-range-of-values-to-create-heat-map)

However, the spectrum has a majority of green instead of the ROYGBIV that I'm looking for.

I just want the values that I can use as a string, other methods such as the "colours" package here: https://pypi.org/project/colour/ give me a "Color" type object that I can't convert to string.