# PIL: Generating Vertical Gradient Image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gradient

In Android, I used the following code to generate a gradient background that I need:

```
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="#40000000"
    android:endColor="#00000000"
    android:type="linear" />
```

The background goes from light to relatively dark from top to bottom. I wonder how to do the same in Python with PIL, since I need the same effect on another program written in Python.

Comment: What RGB values result from `"#40000000"`?

Comment: @martineau looks (160, 160, 160) is the closest one. Thanks.

Comment: How many pixels vertically?  Would you care if it's in Numpy or scipy instead?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense from the documentation I just [found](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#attr_android:startColor). It looks more like something with an ARGB value of (64, 0, 0, 0). Also, do you know how big of an image is needed?

Comment: @martineau it's 640*640. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Back2Basics Numpy or Scipy is okay for me as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's something that shows ways to draw multicolor rectangular horizontal and vertical gradients.

```
rom PIL import Image, ImageDraw

BLACK, DARKGRAY, GRAY = ((0,0,0), (63,63,63), (127,127,127))
LIGHTGRAY, WHITE = ((191,191,191), (255,255,255))
BLUE, GREEN, RED = ((0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0), (255, 0, 0))


class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y

class Rect(object):
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        minx, maxx = (x1,x2) if x1 < x2 else (x2,x1)
        miny, maxy = (y1,y2) if y1 < y2 else (y2,y1)
        self.min = Point(minx, miny)
        self.max = Point(maxx, maxy)

    width  = property(lambda self: self.max.x - self.min.x)
    height = property(lambda self: self.max.y - self.min.y)


def gradient_color(minval, maxval, val, color_palette):
    """ Computes intermediate RGB color of a value in the range of minval
        to maxval (inclusive) based on a color_palette representing the range.
    """
    max_index = len(color_palette)-1
    delta = maxval - minval
    if delta == 0:
        delta = 1
    v = float(val-minval) / delta * max_index
    i1, i2 = int(v), min(int(v)+1, max_index)
    (r1, g1, b1), (r2, g2, b2) = color_palette[i1], color_palette[i2]
    f = v - i1
    return int(r1 + f*(r2-r1)), int(g1 + f*(g2-g1)), int(b1 + f*(b2-b1))

def horz_gradient(draw, rect, color_func, color_palette):
    minval, maxval = 1, len(color_palette)
    delta = maxval - minval
    width = float(rect.width)  # Cache.
    for x in range(rect.min.x, rect.max.x+1):
        f = (x - rect.min.x) / width
        val = minval + f * delta
        color = color_func(minval, maxval, val, color_palette)
        draw.line([(x, rect.min.y), (x, rect.max.y)], fill=color)

def vert_gradient(draw, rect, color_func, color_palette):
    minval, maxval = 1, len(color_palette)
    delta = maxval - minval
    height = float(rect.height)  # Cache.
    for y in range(rect.min.y, rect.max.y+1):
        f = (y - rect.min.y) / height
        val = minval + f * delta
        color = color_func(minval, maxval, val, color_palette)
        draw.line([(rect.min.x, y), (rect.max.x, y)], fill=color)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Draw a three color vertical gradient.
    color_palette = [BLUE, GREEN, RED]
    region = Rect(0, 0, 730, 350)
    width, height = region.max.x+1, region.max.y+1
    image = Image.new("RGB", (width, height), WHITE)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    vert_gradient(draw, region, gradient_color, color_palette)
    image.show()
    #image.save("vert_gradient.png", "PNG")
    #print('image saved')
```

And here's the image it generates and displays:

[image: screenshot of gradient image created]

This calculates the intermediate colors in the [RGB color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_space), but other colorspaces could be used — for examples compare results of my answers to the question [Range values to pseudocolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901085/range-values-to-pseudocolor).

This could easily be extended to generate RGBA (RGB+Alpha) mode images.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code just now and received this error: `delta = 1:              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` (Removing the `:` (colon) solves the error). I'm on Python 2.7.12 but don't think that is the reason. Great imaging BTW!

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: Thanks for the complement and heads-up. The code got messed up when I attempted to clean-up some changes someone else made to it to handle `delta` being zero — fixed.

Comment: Thanks for updating. I linked to your answer on my own answer on this site just now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63200562/6929343

Answer (score 10):

If you only need two colours, this can be done very simply:

```py
def generate_gradient(
        colour1: str, colour2: str, width: int, height: int) -> Image:
    """Generate a vertical gradient."""
    base = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), colour1)
    top = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), colour2)
    mask = Image.new('L', (width, height))
    mask_data = []
    for y in range(height):
        mask_data.extend([int(255 * (y / height))] * width)
    mask.putdata(mask_data)
    base.paste(top, (0, 0), mask)
    return base
```

This creates a layer in each colour, then creates a mask with transparency varying according to the `y` position. You can replace `y / height` in line 10 with `x / width` for a horizontal gradient, or any function of `x` and `y` for another gradient.

Comment: There's no need to calculate the expression `int(255 * (y / height))` for each of the `width` pixels — you could replace the whole `for x in range(width):` loop with the line `mask_data.extend(width * [int(255 * (y / height))])`. The overall approach you're suggesting could be extended to handle more than two colors by applying it multiple times between consecutive pairs of colors and combining the images.

Comment: @martineau Applied that optimisation.

Comment: That will proably speed things up to some degree. In my own answer I used `ImageDraw.line()` to avoid having to create those pixel values at all — which would be another alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Making some modifications to @martineau's code, this function handles gradient orientation in degrees (not only vertical or horizontal):

```
from PIL import Image
import math


BLACK, DARKGRAY, GRAY = ((0,0,0), (63,63,63), (127,127,127))
LIGHTGRAY, WHITE = ((191,191,191), (255,255,255))
BLUE, GREEN, RED = ((0, 0, 255), (0, 255, 0), (255, 0, 0))


class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    def rot_x(self, degrees):
        radians = math.radians(degrees)
        return self.x * math.cos(radians) + self.y * math.sin(radians)


class Rect(object):
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        minx, maxx = (x1,x2) if x1 < x2 else (x2,x1)
        miny, maxy = (y1,y2) if y1 < y2 else (y2,y1)
        self.min = Point(minx, miny)
        self.max = Point(maxx, maxy)

    def min_max_rot_x(self, degrees):
        first = True
        for x in [self.min.x, self.max.x]:
            for y in [self.min.y, self.max.y]:
                p = Point(x, y)
                rot_d = p.rot_x(degrees)
                if first:
                    min_d = rot_d
                    max_d = rot_d
                else:
                    min_d = min(min_d, rot_d)
                    max_d = max(max_d, rot_d)
                first = False
        return min_d, max_d

    width  = property(lambda self: self.max.x - self.min.x)
    height = property(lambda self: self.max.y - self.min.y)


def gradient_color(minval, maxval, val, color_palette):
    """ Computes intermediate RGB color of a value in the range of minval
        to maxval (inclusive) based on a color_palette representing the range.
    """
    max_index = len(color_palette)-1
    delta = maxval - minval
    if delta == 0:
        delta = 1
    v = float(val-minval) / delta * max_index
    i1, i2 = int(v), min(int(v)+1, max_index)
    (r1, g1, b1), (r2, g2, b2) = color_palette[i1], color_palette[i2]
    f = v - i1
    return int(r1 + f*(r2-r1)), int(g1 + f*(g2-g1)), int(b1 + f*(b2-b1))


def degrees_gradient(im, rect, color_func, color_palette, degrees):
    minval, maxval = 1, len(color_palette)
    delta = maxval - minval
    min_d, max_d = rect.min_max_rot_x(degrees)
    range_d = max_d - min_d
    for x in range(rect.min.x, rect.max.x + 1):
        for y in range(rect.min.y, rect.max.y+1):
            p = Point(x, y)
            f = (p.rot_x(degrees) - min_d) / range_d
            val = minval + f * delta
            color = color_func(minval, maxval, val, color_palette)
            im.putpixel((x, y), color)


def gradient_image(color_palette, degrees):
    region = Rect(0, 0, 600, 400)
    width, height = region.max.x+1, region.max.y+1
    image = Image.new("RGB", (width, height), WHITE)
    degrees_gradient(image, region, gradient_color, color_palette, -degrees)
    return image
```

This flexibility comes at the cost of having to set colors pixel by pixel instead of using lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the technique spelled out.  You need 2 layers on top of each other, one for each color.  Then you make the transparency for each increasing for the top layer and decreasing for the bottom layer.  For extra homework you can change the rate of transparency to an ascending logarithmic scale rather than linear.  Have fun with it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Artemis's code here is the one for top-right corner to botom-left corner gradient.

```
def generate_gradient(
        colour1: str, colour2: str, width: int, height: int) -> Image:
    """Generate a vertical gradient."""
    base = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), colour1)
    top = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), colour2)
    mask = Image.new('L', (width, height))
    mask_data = []
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            mask_data.append(int(255 * ( (x*(height-y)) / (width*height) )))
    mask.putdata(mask_data)
    base.paste(top, (0, 0), mask)
    return base
```