# Python PIL/imagemagick merge gradient over the base image

Tags: python, image-processing, imagemagick, python-imaging-library, imagemagick-convert

I already know how to get a gradient image but how can I merge the gradient image and the base image so that it looks something like this:
[link](https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aoi-6MWkMNN4kGLYNmqN9dm1nrOD)

```
convert -size 1327x1327 xc:transparent gradient: grad_image.png
```

or another approach has been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530345/python-pil-generating-vertical-gradient-image)
Base image is [image: base image]
The output should the gradient at the bottom like this: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aoi-6MWkMNN4kGLYNmqN9dm1nrOD

Comment: Where is the base image? Your `xc:transparent` is pointless, by the way - you can remove it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've edited the question. The output image should have a  gradient at the bottom of the image as shown  [here](https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aoi-6MWkMNN4kGLYNmqN9dm1nrOD)

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. You have a blue jellyfish image and some words, which I don't know how you generate on a black-white gradient. There is also no indication of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MarkSetchell if you see the output image that has white background and title at the bottom, you will notice that there is a black to white gradient at the bottom beneath the title on that image. So if I have any image and I want to add this type of gradient how can I achieve this.

Comment: What's it got to do with the jellyfish? Do you want to paint white on the jellyfish? How's the answer supposed to look? Just describe it in words if you can't create the actual image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ignore the jelly fish image for now. I only want to know about the black-white gradient at the bottom of any image just like the same output in the question. ( I'll edit my question and remove this jelly image)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117775/discussion-between-abhi-and-mark-setchell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only guess what you are trying to do, so my first attempt would be this:

```
convert jelly.jpg \( -size 1140x100! gradient:none-black \) -gravity south -composite -pointsize 36 -fill white -annotate +0+20 "Title Treatment" result.png
```

[image]

The important parts are that the gradient goes from black to **transparent** rather than black to **white**, else you will get white on your background which I am guessing you don't want.

The `-gravity south` places the gradient at the bottom and also sets the initial position of the title, but that is then shifted 20 pixels up from the bottom with `-annotate +0+20`.

Hope that helps.

**Update 1**

If you want to control the gradient, you can alter the start and end of it using `rgb()` constants, like this:

```
convert jelly.jpg \( -size 1140x100! gradient:"rgba(0,0,0,0.25)"-"rgb(50,50,50)" \) -gravity south -composite -pointsize 36 -fill white -annotate +0+20 "Title Treatment" result.png
```

[image]

Or you can make it go from one colour to another:

```
convert jelly.jpg \( -size 1140x100! gradient:"rgba(0,0,0,0.25)"-"rgba(255,255,0,0.75)" \) -gravity south -composite -pointsize 36 -fill white -annotate +0+20 "Title Treatment" result.png
```

[image]

Or you can change the blending mode, so here I use `colorBurn`:

```
convert jelly.jpg \( -size 1140x100! gradient:"rgba(0,0,0,0.25)"-"rgba(255,255,0,0.75)" \) -gravity south -compose colorburn -composite -pointsize 36 -fill white -annotate +0+20 "Title Treatment" result.png
```

[image]

If you want to try some other blending modes, you can get a list with:

```
identify -list compose:

Atop
Blend
Blur
Bumpmap
ChangeMask
Clear
ColorBurn
ColorDodge
Colorize
CopyAlpha
CopyBlack
CopyBlue
CopyCyan
CopyGreen
Copy
CopyMagenta
CopyRed
CopyYellow
Darken
DarkenIntensity
DivideDst
DivideSrc
Dst
Difference
Displace
Dissolve
Distort
DstAtop
DstIn
DstOut
DstOver
Exclusion
HardLight
HardMix
Hue
In
Intensity
Lighten
LightenIntensity
LinearBurn
LinearDodge
LinearLight
Luminize
Mathematics
MinusDst
MinusSrc
Modulate
ModulusAdd
ModulusSubtract
Multiply
None
Out
Overlay
Over
PegtopLight
PinLight
Plus
Replace
Saturate
Screen
SoftLight
Src
SrcAtop
SrcIn
SrcOut
SrcOver
VividLight
Xor
```

**Update 2**

If you want to blur the text, it is easier to create that first, blur it, and then underlay the background like this:

```
convert -size 1140x100! gradient:none-black     \
   -pointsize 36 -fill white -gravity south     \
   -annotate +5+25 "Title Treatment" -blur 0x4  \
   -annotate +0+20 "Title Treatment" jelly.jpg +swap -composite result.png
```

[image]

**Update 3**

If you want to shadow your text, and control your gradient and do a load of other things, you may be better off doing one thing at a time. So, let's try and make your text with a drop-shadow first, then put a gradient on your image then put the shadowed text on top of that - and hope we are getting close!

```
string="Funky Main Title\nSub-title"
convert -size 1200x400 xc:none -pointsize 72 -gravity center   \
       -fill white  -stroke black  -annotate +25+65 "$string"  \
       \( +clone -background black  -shadow 70x4+5+5 \) +swap  \
       -background none -flatten  -trim +repage shadowed.png
```

[image]

Now put gradient on main image and title top of that:

```
convert jelly.jpg                                                   \
  \( -size 1140x100! gradient:"rgba(0,0,0,0.25)"-"rgb(50,50,50)" \) \
  -gravity south -composite                                         \
  shadowed.png -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! This is what I wanted.

Comment: Excellent! Pleased to be of service - good luck with your project.

Comment: Mark is there a way I can control the transparency of this gradient

Comment: I was trying to add text shadow for the title using `convert jelly.jpg \( -size 1140x100! gradient:none-black \) -gravity south -composite -pointsize 36 -fill white -annotate +5+25 "Title Treatment"  -blur 0x4 -annotate +0+20 "Title Treatment" result.png`

not working the bottom half is getting blured

Comment: Mark if I have 2 lines in the title like:

**   Hello
  This is Me**

and we are doing blur on both the titles as 
`-annotate +5+25 Hello -blur 0x2 -annotate +5+25 This is Me -blur 0x2`

The second time i do blur for `This is Me`  the title 'Hello' as get blurred

What's wrong

Comment: Use `-annotate +5+25 "Line 1\nLine 2"`

Comment: Cool ! awesome, How did you master this. I tried to read stuff online and everything gets messed up

Comment: Years of frustration, practice, experiment... :-)

Comment: `gradient:"rgba(0,0,0,0.25)"-"rgba(255,255,0,0.75)" `
the command is taking hours to run if I use a  high resolution image

Comment: sorry my bad there was a space between`"rgba(0,0,0,0.25)"-"rgba(255,255,0,0.75)"`

Comment: also if we add these `"rgba(0,0,0,0.25)"-"rgba(255,255,0,0.75)"` the gradient strip becomes visible is there a way to merge or blend it with the base image ?

Comment: Experiment with changing the `0.25` and `0.75` to numbers between 0 and 1 to get the effect you want.

Comment: And If I want to overlay the `string` on the image with text-shadow. Lets say that I have image abc.png and I want to write hello along with its shadow.

Comment: Have another look at **Update 3**.

Comment: Mark if I use the -blur option the whole image is betting blurred instead of the text only
`-annotate +30+25 'Hello\nMark' -blur 0x4 -fill red -annotate +25+20  'Hello\nMark' `

Comment: Mark in the Update 2 if we fill the color as white then its working fine. But if I fill black shadow it wont work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117869/discussion-between-abhi-and-mark-setchell).