# OSError: cannot open resources error while running .exe file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I just wrote the barcode generator code. The work of the program is to generate the code. I am taking data through the **XML** file then I will generate the barcode. Everything is working fine in .py file but when I convert the **.py file to .exe** file then it will not generate the barcode then shows **OSError: cannot open resources**.
My code is

```
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
import xml.dom.minidom

DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse('codedata.xml')
ENVELOPE = DOMTree.documentElement
QRCODE = ENVELOPE.getElementsByTagName("QRCODE")[0]
INVOICE = QRCODE.getElementsByTagName('INVOICE')[0]
dataget=INVOICE.childNodes[0].data
with open('barcode_image.jpeg', 'wb') as f:
    barcode.Code128(str(dataget),writer=ImageWriter()).write(f) # error shows in this line
```

[image: Error Image (output Image)]

I don't know what to do please help me.

Comment: Try searching? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47694421/pil-issue-oserror-cannot-open-resource#48968457

Comment: Please make a note to paste the error message __as text__, and next time you put a question here. Did you try splitting the line up to work out which part is raising the error?