# Create a function mapping a number in (0,1) to a color between blue and red

Tags: python, colors

I want to create a function `colfunc` that receives as argument a number between `0` and `1` and returns a color between blue and red, where blue would correspond to a `0` and red to a `1`. The ultimate goal is to do something like the following

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
a=[1,2,3]
plt.plot(a,color=colfunc(0))
```

and it should plot a blue line
or alternatively if I do

```
plt.plot(a,color=colfunc(1))
```

it should return a red line. This is straightforward, but then I also want to be able to do, for example,

```
plt.plot(a,color=colfunc(0.1))
```

and it should return a line of the color of a tonality of purple that is closer to blue than to red and so on.

Comment: Take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10902473/355230) to a related question about generating color gradients.

Comment: Can you post any code, input, errors, or desired ouput

Comment: @martineau I will study your file to see if there is the solution to my problem. Meanwhile, I have restated the question in order to make it more clear. T.Y.

Comment: 3sm1r: Oops, I posted a link to the wrong answer (I answered the linked question twice). To make up for the mistake, see the answer to your question I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is called [Linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) (sometimes abbreviated to "LERP"). In this case the interpolation is between to two colors in the RGB [colorspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space).

Here's how to use the `pseudocolor()` function in [one answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10907855/355230) to the question [Range values to pseudocolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901085/range-values-to-pseudocolor) to do what it sounds like you want. (I've renamed it `colfunc()` as per your question.)

```
def colfunc(val, minval, maxval, startcolor, stopcolor):
    """ Convert value in the range minval...maxval to a color in the range
        startcolor to stopcolor. The colors passed and the one returned are
        composed of a sequence of N component values (e.g. RGB).
    """
    f = float(val-minval) / (maxval-minval)
    return tuple(f*(b-a)+a for (a, b) in zip(startcolor, stopcolor))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    RED, YELLOW, GREEN  = (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0)
    CYAN, BLUE, MAGENTA = (0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1)
    steps = 10
    minval, maxval = 0.0, 1.0
    incr = (maxval-minval)/steps

    print('val       R      G      B')
    for i in range(steps+1):
        val = minval + round(i*incr, 1)
        print('{:.1f} -> ({:.3f}, {:.3f}, {:.3f})'.format(
                    val, *colfunc(val, minval, maxval, BLUE, RED)))
```

Output:

```
val       R      G      B
0.0 -> (0.000, 0.000, 1.000)
0.1 -> (0.100, 0.000, 0.900)
0.2 -> (0.200, 0.000, 0.800)
0.3 -> (0.300, 0.000, 0.700)
0.4 -> (0.400, 0.000, 0.600)
0.5 -> (0.500, 0.000, 0.500)
0.6 -> (0.600, 0.000, 0.400)
0.7 -> (0.700, 0.000, 0.300)
0.8 -> (0.800, 0.000, 0.200)
0.9 -> (0.900, 0.000, 0.100)
1.0 -> (1.000, 0.000, 0.000)
```

Here's a visualization showing the range of colors it will produce for different values within the minimum and maximum limits inclusively (such as 0.0–1.0):

[image: visualization showing the range of colors from blue to red]