# What is the word for colorizing grayscale bitmap

Tags: algorithm, graphics, colors, bitmap

I have a task of converting grayscale (8 bit, 256 levels of gray) bitmap to a colored one, with the function that looks somewhat like this:

```
function colorize(bmp, colorA, colorB)
```

In the end black pixels become colorA, and black pixels become colorB, and grayscale pixels a mix of A and B.

My question is: is there a word for this? I want to search for solutions, but without proper terminology I am lost in search engine results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Color Interpolation** is appropriate term for this problem.

In the simplest case you can make linear interpolation for every R,G,B color.

If more fine and smooth gradient is needed, consider interpolation [in another color spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488957/interpolate-from-one-color-to-another)

Answer (score -2):

If it's only the "term" you're looking for, I think clamping might be your word.
So, for example, in OPENGL, the clamp fonction goes as :

Name
clamp — constrain a value to lie between two further values

*genType clamp( genType x,
    genType minVal,
    genType maxVal);*

Hope this helps

Comment: Clamping is for value range limitation, not for described task