# Get colors values from percentages

Tags: javascript, html, css, rgb, hsl

I have to get color from a percentages between 0% and 200%.

Here's the gradient palette

[image: Gradient]

My actual algorithme is taking 5 colors gradients

```
percentageToColor(perc) {
  perc = Math.trunc(perc);
  perc > 200 ? (perc = 200) : '';
  const hue = 200 - perc;
  return `hsl(${hue}, 100%, 50%)`;
```

I don't see how to adapt it to get only 2 gradient colors ( same Blue from 0 to 100% ,then start adding red red, at 200% all red )

The best is that colors gradient to be generic , but specific blue and red is good too.

I don't find any library to make that.

Comment: `hsl` would be suitable if you had a spectrum going on, not a blend of two colours. For that, you'd want to... blend the colours. First divide the percentage by 200 so you get a number from 0 to 1, and take that much red plus (1-that much) blue.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488957/interpolate-from-one-color-to-another) may have the answers that you're looking for.

Comment: `return 'rgb(' + (perc<100?0:perc-100) + '%,0%,' + (100-Math.abs(perc-100)) + '%)';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the red aspect and blue aspect of RGB based on the percentage you get, then insert them to your `rgb` value.

Here's a working example:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let colorShower = document.querySelector('.color-shower')
  let colorSlider = document.querySelector('#colorSlider')
  let blueAspect = percentage => Math.round(255 * (1 - (percentage - 1) / 200))
  let redAspect = percentage => Math.round(255 * (percentage - 1) / 200)
  let percentage = colorSlider.value
  let buildColor = (redAspect, blueAspect) => `rgb(${redAspect}, 0, ${blueAspect}`
    
  colorShower.style.backgroundColor = buildColor(redAspect(percentage), blueAspect(percentage))
  
  colorSlider.addEventListener('input', e => {
    percentage = colorSlider.value
    colorShower.style.backgroundColor = buildColor(redAspect(percentage), blueAspect(percentage))
  })
}
```

```css
.color-shower {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.color-slider {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class = "color-shower"></div>
<input type = "range" min = "1" max = "200" value = "1" class = "color-slider" id = "colorSlider">
```

Comment: Any way to make this adapt to all combination of 2 colors ?

Comment: @infodev Yes, but you need to change the maths. It shouldn't be too hard to replicate the formula above for different colours.

Comment: @infodev Glad I could help. Do ask if you need additional guidance.