# Display a color from a position on a gradient

Tags: c#, colors, gradient, transition

Using the Kinect, I'm taking height measurements of both hands from a table, and displaying a color on the screen that's determined by the proportion of the heights. For example, if handProportion = .5, the screen would be green. At any other proportion, the screen is red. However, I need green to transition smoothly into red.

My first instinct is color bitshifting, but that sounds complicated. How can I write a function that displays a color from a gradient based on a position value in that gradient?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need to interpolate between two colors given a ratio:
[Color Interpolation Between 3 Colors in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236683/color-interpolation-between-3-colors-in-net)

Comment: interpolate! that was the word i was looking for.