# Get colors between two color HEX refs or RGB

Tags: c#, .net, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Color Interpolation Between 3 Colors in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236683/color-interpolation-between-3-colors-in-net)

I have been trying to get a categories list of colors using C#:

```
Red:
255, 69, 0
255, 99, 71
etc.. 

Green:
0, 250, 154
143, 188, 139
etc...
```

So far I have been pretty unsuccessful. Ideally, what I'd like is a way to supply two HEX refs or RGB refs and get a list back of say 10 colors between those two references. Is this possible in C#?

**EDIT**

Found this... http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/color-blend/ just converting the js to c# now. Will post when its done.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1236683/590790

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not aware of built-in function which would help you, but you can do it yourself.

As long as color can be defined using 3 numbers (R,G,B), you can take two colors:

```
(R1,G1,B1)
(R2,G2,B2)
```

Then divide diff between pairs and produce numbers by intervals.

```
int numberOfIntervals = 10; //or change to whatever you want.
var interval_R = (R2 - R1) / numberOfIntervals;
var interval_G = (G2 - G1) / numberOfIntervals;
var interval_B = (B2 - B1) / numberOfIntervals;

var current_R = R1;
var current_G = G1;
var current_B = B1;

for (var i = 0; i <= numberOfIntervals; i++)
{
    var color = Color.FromRGB(current_R, current_G, current_B);
    //do something with color.

    //increment.
    current_R += interval_R;
    current_G += interval_G;
    current_B += interval_B;
}
```

I haven't compiled the code, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 8):

What you are looking for is called [*interpolation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation). In this particular scenario you need to interpolate data between two *key points*.

Since interpolation is a really common scenario when programming, I [wrote a generic solution for it](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/interpolation-no-more/), easily allowing you to interpolate between two or more key points, using either linear or even [cardinal spline interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline#Cardinal_spline).

Using my library you could calculate intermediate colors as follows:

```
var keyPoints = new CumulativeKeyPointCollection<Color, double>(
    new ColorInterpolationProvider() );

keyPoints.Add( Color.FromArgb(0, 250, 154) );
keyPoints.Add( Color.FromArgb(143, 188, 139) );

var linear = new LinearInterpolation<Color, double>( keyPoints ); 

// E.g. to get a color halfway the two other colors.
Color colorHalfway = linear.Interpolate( 0.5 );
```

You would have to implement `ColorInterpolationProvider` by extending from `AbstractInterpolationProvider<Color, double>`, but this is quite straightforward, and more information can be found [in my blog post](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/interpolation-no-more/).

This example uses the [`Media.Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors.aspx) class, but you could just as well support any other `Color` class by passing along a different interpolation provider.