# Cannot use Color.FromArgb in DataGridView cell BackColor

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, datagridview, colors

I am looping through a `DataGridView` control and adding rows dynamically. I am setting the `BackColor` property of each cell based on the following logic:

```
if (bidVolume != null)
{
    this.Rows[this.RowCount - 1].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
else
{
    this.Rows[this.RowCount - 1].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(150, Color.Green);
}
```

This is causing problems, the color is not properly set visually and when re-sizing the `DataGridView` it looks like this:

[image]

When I don't use `Color.FromArgb` and just use `Color.Red` for example, then everything works fine ..

Is it possible to set a cell `BackColor` using `Color.FromArgb` ?

Thanks

Comment: which version of .NET?

Comment: Old question but...

... = ControlPaint.LightLight(sourceColor)

Does just a good job for me.. there's also Light, Dark and DARKDARK. Just sayin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `Color.FromArgb`, because `DataGridView` won't accept transparent colors. This is probably caused by the fact that the cells and DataGridView are not transparent (by default). What you are looking for is probalby [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252838/get-colors-between-two-color-hex-refs-or-rgb); you may want to set `BackColor` to color between White and Green.

If I am mistaken and this is not what you want please explain your need for alpha channel in the cell.

Comment: @Sherlock there's a way to tackle that but. I will make it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You got the reason why. To overcome this, use the protected `SetStyle` method to override the behaviour. Something like:

```
class MyDgv : DataGridView
{
    public MyDgv()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true); //this is the key

        //and now you can do what you want.
        this.Rows[this.RowCount - 1].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(150, Color.Green);
    }
}
```

[From documentation:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor.aspx)

> The BackColor property does not support transparent colors unless the
>   SupportsTransparentBackColor value of
>   System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles is set to true.
>
> The BackColor property is an ambient property. An ambient property is
>   a control property that, if not set, is retrieved from the parent
>   control. For example, a Button will have the same BackColor as its
>   parent Form by default. For more information about ambient properties,
>   see the AmbientProperties class or the Control class overview.

Comment: @Sherlock I tried too, and it worked. May be you could make it edit your question to show us how you tried and what you tried (or another question).

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I ran into the same issue. The simplest solution is just to use the `Color.FromArgb()` override that excludes the alpha parameter from the constructor. As long as you don't specify an alpha transparency, the color works perfectly.

```
public static Color SeaFoamGreen = Color.FromArgb(20, 125, 115);
```